# Document about files in .git/rebase-apply directory?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is there any document which describes meaning of each file in `.git/rebase-apply` generated while rebasing?

Comment: I have not seen one, and I think the contents have evolved over time.  I don't think you should depend on the contents of this directory.

Comment: @torek I think some of them are quite useful. For example, `original-commit` file seems to tell me which commit is being rebased now.

Answer (score 1):

It's used during rebase and can be deleted by `git rebase --abort`
Sourse: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase